# click the checkbox on another window using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have window A and click a agreement link, it will open window B:

```
pageLinks.onclick = function(){ 
    window.open(this.href, "_blank", "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,width=980,height=750,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=yes,status=yes");
    return false;
}
```

I want to do something like this:

1. On window B, it shows the agreement content, at bottom, there's a  "I agree this agreement" button, click it
2. window B will close
3. at the same time in Window A, the checkbox before the agreement link will be checked.

Can we implement this using Javascript?

Comment: show your checkbox code

Comment: Research: `window.opener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the following javascript code on window B:

```
// when button is clicked
document.getElementById('submitBtn').onclick = function() {

    // check the checkbox on page A
    window.opener.document.getElementById('checkboxElement').checked = true;

    // close page B
    window.close();
}
```

you can use `window.opener` object as long as the window was opened by it, and has the same domain.

make sure to replace `submitBtn` with the button id, and `checkboxElement` with the checkbox id on window A.

hope that helps.